# How to append to file using ob_start

Tags: php, file, append

I have looked for quite a while now, to see if it's possible to "append" to a file if using ob_start with PHP.

I have tried the following but did not work. Any way of achieving this?

```
<?php

$cacheFile = 'file.txt';

if ( (file_exists($cacheFile)) && ((fileatime($cacheFile) + 600) > time()) )
{
$content = file_get_contents($cacheFile);
echo $content;
} else
{
ob_start();
// write content
echo '<h1>Hello world</h1>';
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
file_put_contents($cacheFile,$content,'a+'); // I added the a+
echo $content;
}
?>
```

I borrowed the above example from another post on S.O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) doesn't work that way.  To append, you need to use [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen), [`fwrite`](http://php.net/fwrite) and [`fclose`](http://php.net/fclose) manually.

```
$file = fopen($cacheFile, 'a+');
fwrite($file, $content);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: `file_put_contents` actually supports file appending :)

Comment: @Jack: Didn't actually know that :-P  Now I do!  I'll leave this here anyway.

Comment: Ah, the good 'ol days of when I used to "ask" questions and now I "answer" them. Another word of thanks Rocket ;-)

Answer (score 7):

To append using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) you can simply pass `FILE_APPEND` as the third argument:

```
file_put_contents($cacheFile, $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

It can also be used to apply file locking using the binary OR operator, e.g. `FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX`.